# Azure - React to new blob created

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have a container in a storage account where I used to get new files polled often (multiple times a day) in a dedicated directory by an external party. Now, i want to consume these files, decompress them and download them into my Virtual Machine. Is there a way to listen and store the list of new blobs created so that i can download them together in batch once in every 2 hours? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can react to blob events with Event Grid and allow services such as logc app to decompress and push the files to your VM. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview

If you really need it to be at a 2 hour interval, you need to send the events to a queue via a Function or something similar.